# How to send array js array to php page in ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The problem is I want to send ajax array to a php where I can use it for different processing, actually I have a lot of text fields in my html page and I have assign them name I want to send this name array to my php page through ajax(JavaScript only) where I will receive this array and will use it for different purposes.

Here is my example HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="top_phone_cal2" class="form-control"  >
<input type="text" name="top_phone_cal2" class="form-control"  >
<input type="button" onclick="dis_phone_call2_top()" class="form-control"  >
```

JavaScript code:

```
  function dis_phone_call2_top()
  {
    var x =document.getElementsByName('top_phone_cal2');
    var top_phone_cal2 = [];     
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
      top_phone_cal2[i]=x[i].value;  
      //alert("cars value: "+top_phone_cal2[i]+" loop value: "+x.length);
    }   
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
      {
        var bbb=xmlhttp.responseText;alert(bbb);                                 
      }
    }       
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "intervention_phonecal2_insrt.php?value="+top_phone_cal2, true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
  }
```

Here is php code:

```
<?php
  $top_phone_cal2= $_REQUEST["value"];        
  echo $top_phone_cal2;  
?>
```

The problem in this code is that through this code I am unable to receive array in php page instead of this I receive the variable in php page
For Example:
if in first text field I entered `John`and in second text field I entered `lincon` then in page it display it like this `johnlincon` but I want to display I like this `echo $top_phone_cal2[0]`=john and `echo $top_phone_cal2[1]`=lincon
kindly tell me how to do this?

Comment: Make json of your array using JSON.stringify() and send it as query string..

Comment: how to use it i never did it before?

Comment: There is nothing like an `ajax array`. Read about how HTTP protocol works in general, then about particular implementations for your needs.

Comment: may be there is nothing exist like that but what is the correct or suitable way to do this need your advice...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="top_phone_cal2[]" class="form-control"  />
<input type="text" name="top_phone_cal2[]" class="form-control"  />
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
function dis_phone_call2_top()
{
  var x =document.getElementsByName('top_phone_cal2');
  var top_phone_cal2 = [];
  for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
    top_phone_cal2[i]= x[i].value;
    //alert("cars value: "+top_phone_cal2[i]+" loop value: "+x.length);
  }
  var value_str = 'value[]=' + top_phone_cal2.join('&value[]=')
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
      var bbb=xmlhttp.responseText;alert(bbb);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "intervention_phonecal2_insrt.php?"+value_str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Explanation: you should post the proper format of value in GET params.
PHP collect this value to `$_GET['value']` variable.